# Rollback local files to a previous Github commit

Tags: github

How do I rollback my local files to a previous Git commit from the Terminal? I've read the other similar questions but being a newbie to GitHub I'm still a little puzzled.

My previous commit I want to rollback my local files back to is called 
dd2cf7a782f89ba274a748e0cd704d4c2eb82ce6

Comment: You "check out" the version you want: `git checkout dd2cf...`

Comment: Sounds like a non-git problem; did you rename your project folder? Start a new shell, go to the folder and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Yeh I did, I have now corrected it and the command returns the option to create a branch. I have done this, all looks back to normal! :)

Comment: Careful about "detached heads", if you work off a non-head in git your changeset can drift off into bit space... Read the tutorial.

Comment: Wrote as an answer so you can close this question.

Comment: What would you suggest to do for the next step? I had the following line returned in the command $ HEAD is now at 419cc51 mobile type scale. I want to push this to be the master

Comment: I suggest you read the git tutorial so you know how to approach tasks the way git expects. I'm not sure what task or problem you are running into, but probably what you need is a branch name for your head. Then it becomes something that git wants to move around. Read the tutorial and follow a scenario with branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "check out" the version you want: `git checkout dd2cf7a782f89` should do it (i.e. you can use just part of the changeset hash).